# Python randomizing troubles

Tags: python, arrays, random

I've been trying to make a script to randomize the positions in a group of numbers. EX: I'll give it the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4` and it will spit back `3214, 2341, 4132`, etc. My problem is that after a few iterations it will start giving me output such as `1421, 3421, 2421`. Here is my code,

```
def Solution():
    global A, B, C, D, SOLVED, SOL, A1, B1, C1, D1
    Attempts = []
    Orderer = []
    A1 = 0
    B1 = 0
    C1 = 0
    D1 = 0
    while SOLVED != True:
        MASTER = ""
        A1 = randint(1, 4)
        B1 = randint(1, 4)
        C1 = randint(1, 4)
        D1 = randint(1, 4)
        while B1 == A1:
            B1 = randint(1, 4)
            #print("B1 is the same")
        while C1 == B1 or C1 == A1:
            C1 = randint(1, 4)
            #print("C1 is the same")
        while D1 == C1 or D1 == B1 or D1 == A1:
            D1 = randint(1, 4)
            #print("D1 is the same")
        for i in range(4):
            if A1 == i:
                Orderer.append(A)
            elif B1 == i:
                Orderer.append(B)
            elif C1 == i:
                Orderer.append(C)
            elif D1 == i:
                Orderer.append(D)
        for i in range(4):
            MASTER = MASTER + str(Orderer[i - 1])
        if MASTER in Attempts:
            print("{} was already guessed".format(MASTER))
            continue
        print(MASTER)

        if MASTER == SOL:
            print("Solution: {}".format(MASTER))
            SOLVED = True
        Attempts.append(MASTER)

        MASTER = ""
        Orderer.clear()
```

Note: Just some clarifications;
Variables A, B, C, and D are the 1, 2, 3, 4 listed above.
I gave the computer a "solution" under `SOL` so it doesn't run infinitely. In this case, the solution is `1234`.
Also, I put a check so it doesn't make combinations it already made. It's stored under attempts.
A1, B1, C1, and D1 are the position values for A, B, C, and D. They are pumped into the orderer and put then get stored in that order.

Comment: Did you try using the `random.shuffle` function?

Comment: Or anything from itertools? (combinations, permutations)

Comment: If you are still learning, then it is useful to code things like shuffles (which is what you want here) from first principles.  Start with the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understanding your use-case, but I would recommend taking a look at the library `itertools`. It is really awesome at things like combinations and permutations.

```
import itertools
import random
all_permutations = list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4]))
random.shuffle(all_permutations)
print(all_permutations)
```